# SQLITE: Update all records using concatenation but using the information from each row its on

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im having a bit of trouble. I am trying to update all records with the concatenation operator which allows me to create new strings and update specific fields with the new created string. Thing is, its working partially as its selecting the data from record 1 and applying that to all my records!

I need it to update each record using the data from that record not just from the first one.

**Table layout:**

```
trackpath|artistname|trackname
```

**Example data i return:**

```
location/rihanna - work.mp3|rihanna|work
location/rihanna - work.mp3|james blunt|beautiful
```

**Expected data:**

```
location/rihanna - work.mp3|rihanna|work
location/james blunt - beautiful.mp3|james blunt|beautiful
```

**Update statement:**

```
update table set trackpath = (SELECT 'location/' || artistname || ' - ' || trackname from table || '.mp3')
```

P.s, i tried where rowid = rowid in the select statement but same result!

Comment: How do we "know" that the Rihanna record doesn't need to be updated, or should we assume that every record gets updated?

Comment: Every record needs to be updated!:)

Comment: Because you have paths, which may of arbitrary length and depth, this will be tough to do in SQLite.  I wouldn't do the update in SQLite if I were you.

Comment: Regex would probably be the easiest tool here, but SQLite does not support it.  Think of what you need to do.  You need to find the _last_ forward slash and then substring up to it.  Sounds simple but is not in SQLite.

Comment: Do you know exactly how many slashes are in every path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want the subquery to return different values for different rows, you must use a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub) and specifiy how the data in the subquery relates to the data in the outer query:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET x = (SELECT ...
         FROM MyTable AS T2
         WHERE T2.id = MyTable.id);
```

However, if you use only values from the same row, you do not need a subquery at all:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET trackpath = 'location/' || artistname || ' - ' || trackname || '.mp3';
```

Comment: Wow! Exactly what i wanted and it executed instantly. Thank you very much!